RDMA access flags validation
If we receive Send or Send with Immediate packets but don't have local write access right in RC, UC, or UD, what behavior should we expect?
I think that there’s a local protection error in the target, and in the initiator will encounter a failure

Are you mixing C and C++ languages?  I highly recommend you avoid mixing them.  The C++ language allows overloading of functions and operators, and the C language doesn't.  This feature complicates the linking of C language functions with C++ languages.  The C++ language also has std::string and std::vector, which also increases the complexity of combining the two languages.  I recommend picking one language and updating your language tags.

I love abbreviations.  For example, my understanding of RC is "resistor-Capacitor" as in an RC circuit.  Please edit your post with the definitions of RC, UC, and UD.

First of all, we need to distinguish QP types from memory access flags.
RC, UC, UD are QP types that included in ibv_qp_init_attr which can be specified before we create QP. The following is structure of ibv_qp_init_attr.
struct ibv_qp_init_attr {
    void                   *qp_context;     /* Associated context of the QP */
    struct ibv_cq          *send_cq;        /* CQ to be associated with the Send Queue (SQ) */
    struct ibv_cq          *recv_cq;        /* CQ to be associated with the Receive Queue (RQ) */
    struct ibv_srq         *srq;            /* SRQ handle if QP is to be associated with an SRQ, otherwise NULL */
    struct ibv_qp_cap       cap;            /* QP capabilities */
    enum ibv_qp_type        qp_type;        /* QP Transport Service Type: IBV_QPT_RC, IBV_QPT_UC, IBV_QPT_UD, IBV_QPT_RAW_PACKET or IBV_QPT_DRIVER */
    int                     sq_sig_all;     /* If set, each Work Request (WR) submitted to the SQ generates a completion entry */
};

struct ibv_qp_cap {
    uint32_t                max_send_wr;    /* Requested max number of outstanding WRs in the SQ */
    uint32_t                max_recv_wr;    /* Requested max number of outstanding WRs in the RQ */
    uint32_t                max_send_sge;   /* Requested max number of scatter/gather (s/g) elements in a WR in the SQ */
    uint32_t                max_recv_sge;   /* Requested max number of s/g elements in a WR in the RQ */
    uint32_t                max_inline_data;/* Requested max number of data (bytes) that can be posted inline to the SQ, otherwise 0 */
};

But memory access flags are the permissions that we want to give when we register a piece of memory through the RDMA card. It can be specified by setting the access parameter in function ibv_reg_mr.
struct ibv_mr *ibv_reg_mr(struct ibv_pd *pd, void *addr, size_t length, int access);

The argument access describes the desired memory protection attributes; it is either 0 or the bitwise OR of one or more of the following flags:
   IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE  Enable Local Write Access

   IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE  Enable Remote Write Access

   IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_READ Enable Remote Read Access

   IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_ATOMIC Enable Remote Atomic Operation Access (if supported)

   IBV_ACCESS_MW_BIND Enable Memory Window Binding

   IBV_ACCESS_ZERO_BASED Use byte offset from beginning of MR to access this MR, instead of a pointer address

   IBV_ACCESS_ON_DEMAND Create an on-demand paging MR

   IBV_ACCESS_HUGETLB Huge pages are guaranteed to be used for this MR, applicable with IBV_ACCESS_ON_DEMAND in explicit mode only

   IBV_ACCESS_RELAXED_ORDERING Allow system to reorder accesses to the MR to improve performance

   If IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE or IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_ATOMIC is set, then IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE must be set too.

   Local read access is always enabled for the MR.

   ... excerpt from `man ibv_reg_mr`

So, "don't have local write access right" means that we register a piece of memory and give it a access equal 0. We can check the completion status and vendor error by checking the work completion ibv_wc.
 struct ibv_wc {
    uint64_t                wr_id;          /* ID of the completed Work Request (WR) */
    enum ibv_wc_status      status;         /* Status of the operation */
    enum ibv_wc_opcode      opcode;         /* Operation type specified in the completed WR */
    uint32_t                vendor_err;     /* Vendor error syndrome */
    uint32_t                byte_len;       /* Number of bytes transferred */
    union {
               __be32                  imm_data;         /* Immediate data (in network byte order) */
               uint32_t                invalidated_rkey; /* Local RKey that was invalidated */
    };
    uint32_t                qp_num;         /* Local QP number of completed WR */
    uint32_t                src_qp;         /* Source QP number (remote QP number) of completed WR (valid only for UD QPs) */
    unsigned int            wc_flags;       /* Flags of the completed WR */
    uint16_t                pkey_index;     /* P_Key index (valid only for GSI QPs) */
    uint16_t                slid;           /* Source LID */
    uint8_t                 sl;             /* Service Level */
    uint8_t                 dlid_path_bits; /* DLID path bits (not applicable for multicast messages) */
};

we can check out what happened by printing out ibv_wr.status and ibv_mr.vendor_err. check this post (https://www.rdmamojo.com/2013/02/15/ibv_poll_cq/) for more information.
A simple test(QP type = RC)

server (normal)

client: registered memory with access equal 0


The result is:
server vendor_err = 137, operation status = 11, it means IBV_WC_REM_OP_ERR — Remote Operation Error: the operation could not be completed successfully by the responder. Possible causes include a responder QP related error that prevented the responder from completing the request or a malformed WQE on the Receive Queue. Relevant for RC QPs
client vendor_err = 51, operation status = 4, it means IBV_WC_LOC_PROT_ERR  - Local Protection Error: the locally posted Work Request’s buffers in the scatter/gather list does not reference a Memory Region that is valid for the requested operation.

Thank you for your response. It’s possible that I didn’t express my thoughts clearly.
I mean that the specification does not explicitly define the expected behavior in this scenario. However, based on my understanding, when local write access is disabled (set to 0) on the target side, it is reasonable to expect that a protection error should occur. This error would indicate that an unauthorized write operation was attempted despite the disabled access permission
@yupe

@Shegunts Actually, I think you are right. I've fixed the answer with the detailed test.

Thank you for your interest in my query. Could you please investigate the behavior when 'qp_type=rc' and 'opcode=send', and the registered memory has an access level of 0? I am receiving a success message from the initiator side, and the target side is indicating a local protection error. I think that this is the right behaviour. Your assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

There had to be qp_type=uc not rc. @yupe
